# Excel 2007: remove text limitations from cell

Tags: excel-2007

I would like to type at least **500 characters** in excel sheet cell. But when I do that it only lets me add 1 paragraph like **196 characters**. When I add another paragraph, it gives me a message **

> "Exceeded Text Limit"

**. How do I resolve this so I can add lot of text in the cell. I googled and tried different things and failed.

Please help !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a 32,767 character limit in Excel per cell when wrapping text.
You might be able to import it into Access as a Table, with a Memo field that can hold 65,000 characters.
A text box can also hold more, but if you're doing any calculations, this isn't practical.

Try looking here: http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T003163_Character_Limits_for_Cells.html

Comment: how to overcome this issue, I got the same error. "The maximum length of cell contents (text) is 32,767 characters excel c#"

Comment: @GANI: You don't, it's an excel limitation. You can TRUNCATE all text longer than 32767, if you can afford to loose that data.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks for the info

Comment: There's a moose on the loose.